# TFS2015 build alerts not working

Tags: build, tfs-2015

We have TFS 2015 setup with team build alerts. If I create a team alert for Check-ins, all members of the team successfully get an email on code checked-in. If I create a build failure alert and then get the build to fail, no alerts are received by the team. I don't understand why one would work and the other doesn't. SMTP must be setup fine as are team permissions. What could it be? Is there any where i can see logs?

Comment: Which exact version of TFS? And what type of build (XAML or 2015)?

Comment: TFS2015 - Version 14.0.24712.0 - The build is a Visual Studio Build added from the web portal, no idea which one of those things under the hood.

Comment: You are on TFS Update 1, I suggest updating to TFS 2015 update 3 to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a bug in the version of TFS that we are using (SP1) which is fixed in a later update (SP2 or 3). The issue was build events were not being raised by the TfsJobAgent due to an error:

Exception Message: TF10121: The path '$(SourcePath)' is not found or not supported. Type or select a different path. (type InvalidPathException)

[image: $(SourcePath) issue]

The $(SourcePath) TFS variable is apparently broken but can be bypassed if updated to the SourcePath in the Variables Tab:

[image: Valid Source Path]

I have updated our builds with so they are using this qualified SourcePath. Build Failure notification emails now being received if you break the build. Apparently Slack integration is now also working!

This is apparently an issue in SP1 and is fixed in later service packs

Answer (score 0):

To narrow down this issue, you can try with below ways:

- Set alerts **just for yourself** to see if you can get an e-mail when the
  build fail. Detail ways please refer [Set alerts, get notified when
  changes occur](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications)
- Double check the query which the alert is based on, there is a default template, you can use it directly such as below picture
  [image]
- Try to use other build alters such as **a build completes** to see
  whether it works
- Look for if there are some related errors in **Event Log**